# Unknown syntax in typescript interface

Tags: syntax, typescript, interface

I have a definition file with this in it:

```
interface _Form {
    Dump:string;
}

interface Form extends _Form { constructor:{ new():Form }; }
```

What is the meaning of `constructor:{ new():Form };`?

If I try to implement this interface with this:

```
class MyForm implements Form {
    Dump:string;
}
```

I get this error:

> Class 'MyForm' incorrect implements interface 'Form'.
>   Types of property 'constructor' are incompatible.
>   Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'new() => Form'.
>   Type 'Function' provides no match for signature 'new(): Form'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is defined that `Form` has a property named `constructor` and it's a `Form` constructor (that is, a function which returns a new instance of `Form`).

To explain, consider the following:

```
class Form {}

type FormConstructor = { new(): Form };
let formCtor: FormConstructor = Form;
let form: Form = new formCtor();
```

You can also define static properties/functions this way:

```
class Form {
    private dump: string;

    constructor() {}

    static fromDump(dump: string): Form {
        let form = new Form();
        form.dump = dump;
        return form;
    }
}

type FormConstructor = {
    new(): Form;
    fromDump: (dump: string) => Form;
};

let form1: Form = new Form();
let form2: Form = Form.fromDump("dump");

let formCtor: FormConstructor = Form;
let form3: Form = new formCtor();
let form4: Form = formCtor.fromDump("dump");
```

A good example for this is the Array ([lib.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1108) & [lib.es6.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1108)) and ArrayConstructor  ([lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1243) & [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L1243)).

In your case though I don't see a reason for this, and you probably just want to define a class constructor:

```
interface Form {
    dump: string;
}

class MyForm implements Form {
    dump: string;

    constructor(dump: string) {
        this.dump = dump;
    }
}
```

You don't need to specify in the interface that implementing classes need to have a ctor, that's a given.

---

#### Edit

If that interface is auto generated then you need to stop using whatever it is that generates it because it's doing an awful job.
That interface is (I'm pretty sure) impossible to implement, here's something close:

```
interface _Form {
    Dump:string;
}

interface Form extends _Form { ctor:{ new():Form }; }

class MyForm implements Form {
    public ctor: { new():Form };
    public Dump: string;

    constructor() {
        this.ctor = MyForm;
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20_Form%20%7B%0D%0A%09Dump%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Form%20extends%20_Form%20%7B%20ctor%3A%7B%20new()%3AForm%20%7D%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyForm%20implements%20Form%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20ctor%3A%20%7B%20new()%3AForm%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%09public%20Dump%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.ctor%20%3D%20MyForm%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

It's exactly the same except that I changed it from `constructor` to `ctor`, and it compiles fine (though still it makes no sense).
If you change the `ctor` to `constructor`:

```
class MyForm implements Form {
    public constructor: { new():Form };
    public Dump: string;

    constructor() {
        this.constructor = MyForm;
    }
}
```

you'll get errors because the class `constructor` (which is a keyword) needs to be a function and only one using that name.

Comment: That interfaces is an auto generated one. What I need is to implement that interface with a class and I've already tried to implement it using a class with a constructor but I still get the error. The only solution I've found is to manually remove the constructor declaration in the interface

Comment: I changed my answer

Comment: I see, I feared it was impossible to implement. Thank you